# Predicate Form - Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic

What is the predicate form for this set:

$$\left\{1, \frac12, \frac13, \frac14, \frac15,\cdots\right\}$$

I understand that the sequence is $a_n=\frac1n, n\ge1$ but how do I represent that in predicate form?

Comment: $\{ x \mid x= \dfrac 1 n, n \in \mathbb N^+ \}$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you mean $\Bbb Z^+$? or just $\Bbb N$, no need the plus there

Comment: @Holo - IMO, $\mathbb N = \{ 0,1,2,\ldots \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA fair enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left\{ x ~\middle|~ \frac 1 x \in \Bbb N \right\}$$

Comment: @zwim "predicate form"